# Setting up Zend debugger in PDT eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, debugging, eclipse-pdt

I want to debug my php pages from eclipse with Apache24 httpd server

I am using thread safe PHP version and have also downloaded thread safe zend debugger.

Following steps I have performed

- Copied ZendDebugger.dll to C:\Softwares\php\php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64\ext
- Copied dummy.php to my Apache htdocs directory
- Added lines to my php.ini zend_extension_ts=C:/Softwares/php/php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64/ext/ZendDebugger.dll
  zend_debugger.allow_hosts=192.168.1.2/32,127.0.0.1/32 
  zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
  zend_debugger.httpd_uid=-1
- Restarted the server.
- My settings in eclipse for php debugger .

  - Debug port : 10000 , Client Host/IP: 192.168.1.2/32,127.0.0.1/32, Debug response timeout : 50000
- Now trying to test my debugger from eclipse but getting timeout exception in order to connect to the above IPs.
- My phpinfo does not show any entry for Zend debugger.

I might be missing something very simple.

Comment: Default zend debugger settings is now: 10137 change it on eclipse or in php.ini, we will switch this in next version. See also tutorial https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf In current nightly we added setttings checker

Comment: @zulus thanks for the reply...i changed it in eclipse but it did not work..do i have to change it in php.ini ?...one question is what is the "/32" appended to ip addresses ?

Comment: /32 is a subnet mask : https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/ipv4/request-an-ipv4-22-from-the-last-8/subnet-mask-information

Comment: If you phpinfo isn't show info for zend debugger, extension isn't installed properly. zend_extension_ts have invalid patch or is incompatible with your php version. Can you try different DLL?

Comment: i downloaded zend studio web debugger PHP 5.5 and 5.6 from here http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads#Windows...i have php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64 installed in my system..which dll else from where should i download ?

Comment: ZendDebugger doesn't work with PHP Thread Safety since 5.3. You have to switch to non-ts (apache 2.2), or use xdebug.

Comment: Downloaded xdebug..followed instructions here https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug...entries in phpInfo() are matching according to the document...downloaded php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll...still its not working

Comment: http://xdebug.org/wizard.php should help with installation valid libraries.

Comment: ok..i get the best one accroding to me installation..i can see the entries in php info file but the debugger is not stopping in the breakpoint

Comment: Found that while starting up the debug session "the message at the bottom shows "waiting for xDebug session" and stuck at 57 %

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize what i have achieved so far and my learnings.

I could set the xdebug up with PHP.
Zend debugger as mentioned in one the posts has restrictions with thread safe apache servers.

My project structure had a initial html page which was calling the php page i wanted to debug. So whenever i was pointing the php web debug configuration to the html page, the xdebug session was not getting intitialized and the BPs were not hitting.

So when i point the debug conf to php the BPs are being hit.

cheers,
Saurav